# How to fix Cannot find name 'Set'

Tags: typescript

I have simple ts file with a simple sum function that just simple add two numbers no Rocket Science here below

```
function sum(a,b){
    return a+b;
}
```

But when I run

```
tsc TypeScript.ts
```

I get this error below?

```
   ts 
    ../../../../node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts:388:23 - error TS2583: Cannot find name 
    'Set'. Do you need to change your target library? Try changing the `lib` compiler option 
    to es2015 or later.
    
    388         interactions: Set<SchedulerInteraction>,
                              ~~~
    
    
    Found 1 error.
```

How can i fix this error?

Comment: Did you do what the error message suggests?

Comment: I don't know how to change compiler ?

Comment: It doesn't say change the compiler, it says change the *option*. https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html

Comment: Sorry i am newbie to TypeScript how can i change lib jonrsharpe?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I searched through StackOverflow and i found the answer. 
Just type this following command in the terminal

```
npm install @types/node --save-dev
```

Then the error will dissapear!

Comment: For those curious about the `--save-dev` flag, note it simply adds the third-party package to the package's development dependencies. It won't be installed when someone runs npm install directly to install your package.

Comment: I gave this an upvote because this is what worked for me and it's not the first thing I tried.  Anyone care to explain why this works?  I'm not connecting the dots...

Answer (score 0):

```bash
npm install @types/node --save-dev
```

Open the command prompt. then paste this code. After installation is complete again run the code.